# prettyphoto media wordpress plugin opening the image as a url not in popup box

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, prettyphoto

I'm working in wordpress with twitter bootstrap theme.i want to use prettyphoto media wordpress plugin to show my newsletters but when i clicked on any image its opening it as a url not in popup box. i have used it before in my another wordpress sites and its working fine but not now.

Here is my code to open an image:

```
<a href="http://projects.flashonmind.com/hoppworldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/MSNCruise.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto" title="This is the description"><img src="http://projects.flashonmind.com/hoppworldwide/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/mar01.jpg" alt="This is the title" /></a>
```

When i have checked the console in mozilla its showing that $(...).prettyPhoto is not a function.

Actualy there are two scripts in my full width template which i have used for some menu content  when i remove these scripts its working fine but i have to use these script so where i have to put my scripts now here are the scripts:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".sec-menu").mouseover(function(e) {
       $("#my-account").css("display","block");
    });
     $(".sec-menu").mouseout(function(e) {
       $("#my-account").css("display","none");
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please include jQuery => 1.8.3 on your theme header to use prettyPhoto.

Comment: thanks for ur answer but i'm using this as a plugin so i dont think that i have to add anything.

Comment: actually you need this one, try with this.

Comment: i have done that also but unfortunatly not working but now i figure it out that i m using  two scripts in my full width template for some menu content when i m removing these scripts its working fine i have included the script in my question which are in my full width template. i have edit my question now